# spark_partition_id takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given error

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to use a pyspark function similar to pandas merge_asof function, but I am running into an error.

Here is an example code.

```
# create two example DataFrames
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'a', 1.0), (3, 'b', 2.0), (5, 'c', 3.0)], ['key', 'value1', 'data'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'd', 4.0), (2, 'e', 5.0), (4, 'f', 6.0)], ['key', 'value2', 'data'])

# join the DataFrames on the nearest key using spark_partition_id
merged_df = df1.join(df2, (df2['key'] == df1['key']) | (spark_partition_id() == spark_partition_id(df2['key']) - 1), 'leftOuter')

merged_df.show()
```

Comment: Can you also please paste the error message

Comment: `spark_partition_id takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are encountering is likely due to the use of spark_partition_id() in the join condition. spark_partition_id() is a function that returns the ID of the partition in which a given row is located, and it cannot be used in a join condition like this.

To perform a merge similar to pandas merge_asof in PySpark, you can use the rangeBetween function on a window partitioned by the key column. Here's an example code snippet that achieves this.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
# create two example DataFrames

spark = SparkSession.builder.config("driver-class-path","/home/cdsw/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar").config("jars","/home/cdsw/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar").appName("e2ereview").getOrCreate()

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'a', 1.0), (3, 'b', 2.0), (5, 'c', 3.0)], ['key', 'value1', 'data'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'd', 4.0), (2, 'e', 5.0), (4, 'f', 6.0)], ['key', 'value2', 'data'])

# define a window to use for the join
w = Window.partitionBy('key').orderBy('key', 'data').rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

# merge the DataFrames on the nearest key using the window
merged_df = df1.join(df2, df1.key==df2.key, 'leftOuter') \
              .withColumn('nearest_data', func.first(df1.data).over(Window.partitionBy(df1.key).orderBy(df1.key, df1.data).rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))) \
              .orderBy(df1.key)

merged_df.show()
```

Comment: It's throwing the parse Exception error. `mismatched input < expecting {<EOF>, '-'} line 1 pos 17)`

Comment: Apologies hopes this works for you now.